# Eclipse Tomcat default url

Tags: eclipse, url, tomcat

I run my web application using eclipse with tomcat I receive this problem (in internal browser of eclipse - internet explorer):
    http://localhost:8080/MyApp/
    This program cannot display the webpage ....
Because I am after the proxy.
but when I manually put http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/ - it works.
Is possible to adjust settings of Eclipse to launch url like: 127.0.0.1:8080 instead of localhost?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the "Servers View" , double click your tomcat server, the local configuration will appear.Change the hostname to "127.0.0.1" and then save.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to solve your problem. Eclipse built-in browser can use the native proxy settings. Add to the exception list the *localhost* string. Moreover maybe you should make changes in the network connections settings panel in Eclipse: from Direct to Native.